# What is the best approach to show only a specific country using OpenLayers 6

Tags: openlayers

So what I want the view to show is only the map of Bulgaria like shown in this picture [Bulgaria map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCINQ.jpg)

I want the user to not be able to drag the view outside the boundaries of this picture and after zooming to be able to see the full country but again not be able to go too much outside the country. This is the code I am using for now without the limitations that I need.
HTML:

```
  <h2>Bulgaria Map</h2>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
  .map {
  margin: 0 auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: 70%;
    
  }
</style>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([ 24.184119,41.971153])),
name: 'Bulgaria',

});

const map = new ol.Map({
target: 'map',
layers: [
new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM(),
}),
new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [iconFeature]
  }),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      anchor: [0.5, 46],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
      src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/data/icon.png'
    })
  })
})
],
view: new ol.View({
center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([25.4833, 42.7250]),
zoom: 6,
maxZoom: 15,
minZoom: 7,



  })
 });
</script>
```

What I found so far is the extend attribute but I am not sure how to do it correctly so I achieve the restriction to be as the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define the country's extent:

```
   const bulgariaExtent = ol.proj.transformExtent([22.345023234, 41.238104147, 28.603526238, 44.228434539], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

You can then buffer it by 100km (projection units, not geodesic distance) or whatever distance you prefer, as a view constraint:

```
    view: new ol.View({
      extent: ol.extent.buffer(bulgariaExtent, 100000),
      showFullExtent: true,
```

Comment: thank you that worked perfectly now i need to understand what exactly it did and how :D